# "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread" even when method is wrapped in proxy

Tags: spring-aop, spring-transactions, hibernate-4.x, spring-4

I'm getting following error:

```
    org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
at com.test.serviceimpl.EbayCredentialImpl.getCredential(EbayCredentialImpl.java:22)
at com.test.serviceimpl.EbayCredentialImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3f81c256.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
at com.test.serviceimpl.EbayCredentialImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a9d77df8.getCredential(<generated>)
at com.test.jobs.EbayJob_FetchOrders.fetchAndUpdateOrders_Execute(EbayJob_FetchOrders.java:64)
at com.test.jobs.EbayJob_FetchOrders.execute(EbayJob_FetchOrders.java:48)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

---

related spring configs:

```
<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> <!-- annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />
......
```

with NO `hibernate.current_session_context_class`.

```
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="transactionInterceptor" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="Throwable"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.test.jobs.*.*Job*.*_Execute(..))" advice-ref="transactionInterceptor"/>
</aop:config>
```

---

As you can see, the method is wrapped in proxy, still no session found! 
The method is run by a scheduler's job, not a controller method, it gets daos etc from spring context. the transaction etc is working good on controller methods, where i'm using @transactional.

Versions: hibernate-4.3.5, spring-4.0.4

Any clue is appreciated.

Comment: How are you configuring/coding the scheduling part? I see Quartz in your stack trace but none of the Spring Quartz classes.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to configure your transaction manager as annotation-driven you dont need code below

```
<tx:advice id="transactionInterceptor" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="Throwable"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.test.jobs.*.*Job*.*_Execute(..))" advice-ref="transactionInterceptor"/>
</aop:config>
```

just @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) will handle it with

```
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

However i think you can set (propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) only at function level as

```
@Service
public class SomeService{

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void useDataSource() {
//save record
}

}
```